# Is there a python package that can use app-specific password on iCloud/AppleId?

Tags: python, icloud, icloud-api, icloud-documents

I want to enhance a component in a smart hub. It connects against iCloud to gather some data.
But do to the need of 2FA, it's very annoying to re-auth every couple of days.

Other services are able to use the authentication method with so called app-specific passwords and are able to use iCloud data. This would be my goal to do so with that component in the smart hub.

As pyiCloud isn't able to authenticate by app-specific password, I'm looking for a package and/or documentation on how to connect to iCloud with AppleID and app-specific password.

Crawling the documentation at Apple didn't bring up what I'm looking for. May be I'm searching with wrong keywords.

Who can help with a hint or more?

Comment: Your question is off-topic.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. I am trying to turn off 2fa on my icloud. it it not working.